# 60th minute printed in java clock

Tags: java, clock

I'm not sure why this occurs, but the 60th minute gets printed in the results when it should change to hour after minute 59.

Here is my class and main program:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BoundedCounter minutes = new BoundedCounter(59);
        BoundedCounter hours = new BoundedCounter(23);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 121) {
            System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes);   // the current time printed
            if (minutes.getValue() >= 59) {
                hours.getValue();
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

//BoundedCounter

```
    public class BoundedCounter {
        private int value;
        private int upperLimit;

        public BoundedCounter(int upperLimit) {
            this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
        }

        public void next() {
            if (this.value >= this.upperLimit) {
                this.value = 0;
            } else {
                this.value++;
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            if (this.value < 10) {
                return "" + 0 + value;
            } else {
                return "" + value;
            }
        }

        public int getValue() {
            if (this.value <= this.upperLimit) {
                return this.value++;
            } else {
                return this.value = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some results:

> 01:56
>   01:57
>   01:58
>   01:59
>   **02:60**
>   02:00
>   02:01
>   02:02
>   02:03
>   02:04
>   02:05
>   02:06
>   02:07
>   02:08
>   02:09
>   02:10
>   02:11
>   02:12
>   02:13
>   02:14
>   02:15
>   02:16
>   02:17
>   02:18
>   02:19
>   02:20
>   02:21
>   02:22
>   02:23
>   02:24
>   02:25
>   02:26
>   02:27
>   02:28
>   02:29
>   02:30
>   02:31
>   02:32
>   02:33
>   02:34
>   02:35
>   02:36
>   02:37
>   02:38
>   02:39
>   02:40
>   02:41
>   02:42
>   02:43
>   02:44
>   02:45
>   02:46
>   02:47
>   02:48
>   02:49
>   02:50
>   02:51
>   02:52
>   02:53
>   02:54
>   02:55
>   02:56
>   02:57
>   02:58
>   02:59
>   **03:60**
>   03:00
>   03:01
>   03:02
>   03:03
>   03:04
>   03:05

i.e. 2:60 and 3:60 are unexpected output

Comment: Your methods are doing what they are not supposed to do, as far as their names are concerned. See my solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your methods are doing what they are not supposed to do. For example, `getValue()` should only return the value, not increment it. Here is how this can be done:

> Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BoundedCounter minutes = new BoundedCounter(59);
        BoundedCounter hours = new BoundedCounter(23);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 121) {
            System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes);

            minutes.next();                 // counting minutes
            if (minutes.getValue() == 0) {  // when minutes==0, count hours
                hours.next();               // counting hours
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> BoundedCounter.java

```
class BoundedCounter {
    private int value;
    private int upperLimit;

    public BoundedCounter(int upperLimit) {
        this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
    }

    public void next() {
        // when reach the upperLimit, the next value should be 0
        // so >= is not needed, just == will do
        this.value = this.value == this.upperLimit ? 0 : this.value+1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        // using smarter approach to pad with zeros :)
        return String.format("%02d", value);
    }

    public int getValue() {
        // this method should only return the value, not change it in any way
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Some outputs:

> 00:00 00:01 00:02 00:03 00:04 00:05 00:06 00:07 00:08 00:09 00:10
>   00:11 00:12 00:13 00:14 00:15 00:16 00:17 00:18 00:19 00:20 00:21
>   00:22 00:23 00:24 00:25 00:26 00:27 00:28 00:29 00:30 00:31 00:32
>   00:33 00:34 00:35 00:36 00:37 00:38 00:39 00:40 00:41 00:42 00:43
>   00:44 00:45 00:46 00:47 00:48 00:49 00:50 00:51 00:52 00:53 00:54
>   00:55 00:56 00:57 00:58 **00:59 01:00** 01:01 01:02 01:03 01:04 01:05
>   01:06 01:07 01:08 01:09 01:10 01:11 01:12 01:13 01:14 01:15 01:16
>   01:17 01:18 01:19 01:20 01:21 01:22 01:23 01:24 01:25 01:26 01:27
>   01:28 01:29 01:30 01:31 01:32 01:33 01:34 01:35 01:36 01:37 01:38
>   01:39 01:40 01:41 01:42 01:43 01:44 01:45 01:46 01:47 01:48 01:49
>   01:50 01:51 01:52 01:53 01:54 01:55 01:56 01:57 01:58 **01:59 02:00**
>   02:01

Answer (score 1):

You should change the lines :

```
if (this.value <= this.upperLimit) {
    return this.value++;
```

to

```
if (++this.value <= this.upperLimit) {
    return this.value;
```

**AND**

```
if (minutes.getValue() >= 59) {
```

to

```
if (minutes.getValue() == 0) {
```

The problem is that when minutes value is 59 in your code, it is still <= 59, so it gets inside the if block. Then you return 59 to the user and the minutes are now 60.

So, at the next iteration, you first print 60 and *then* you call the `getValue()` method, which turns your minutes to 0.

I guess you are having the same problem when the hour turns 24...

Other than that, consider following a more "expected" functionality of your methods, based on their names, which makes it clear what they do and it becomes easier, even for you to debug. See [Shadowfax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35643900/2516301) for example.

Comment: Nope, this one makes for a new error: 23:53
23:54
23:55
23:56
23:57
23:58
00:59
00:00

Comment: 00:00
00:01
00:02
00:03
00:04
00:05
00:06
00:07
00:08
00:09
00:10
00:11
00:12
00:13
00:14
00:15
00:16
00:17
00:18
00:19
00:20
00:21
00:22
00:23
00:24
00:25
00:26
00:27
00:28
00:29
00:30
00:31
00:32
00:33
00:34
00:35
00:36
00:37
00:38
00:39
00:40
00:41
00:42
00:43
00:44
00:45
00:46
00:47
00:48
00:49
00:50
00:51
00:52
00:53
00:54
00:55
00:56
00:57
00:58
00:59
00:00
00:01
00:02
00:03
00:04
00:05 Sort of does that : (

Comment: It sort of repeats like that in an infinite loop

Comment: @Nebular is it ok now?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing any part of what actually increments your hours or minutes, but it appears to be a problem in your getValue call.

```
public int getValue() {
    if (this.value <= this.upperLimit) {
        return this.value++;
    } else {
        return this.value = 0;
    }
}
```

That `this.value++;` part increments value to 60, and does not roll it over.

Answer (score 0):

there is a slight problem in your approach to create a BoundedCounter
you should not change your counter value when your method name says you just want to read it.Second all your condition check to resets should happen inside your BoundedCounter class only.If you want to reset your counter just expose another method to do that.

Here is the working solution for your reference

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        BoundedCounter minutes = new BoundedCounter(59);
        BoundedCounter hours = new BoundedCounter(23);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 121) {
            if (minutes.hasNext()) {
                minutes.next();
            } else {
                hours.next();
                minutes.resetTo(0);
            }
            System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

class BoundedCounter {
    private int value;
    private int upperLimit;

    public BoundedCounter(int upperLimit) {
        this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
    }

    public void next() {
        ++this.value;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.value < this.upperLimit;
    }

    public void resetTo(int resetValue) {
        this.value = resetValue;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        if (this.hasNext()) {
            return this.value;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (this.value < 10) {
            return "" + 0 + value;
        } else {
            return "" + value;
        }
    }

}
```